# Sql Select Data Mysql Error

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, limit

Newbie want to ask
I want to display the data based on the limit input by the user,
example: user enter a value of 100, and the data will appear as 100.

limit value is always changing according to the value in the input by the user
but there is a problem You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near'' 100'' at line 1.

**please help to resolve this problem ..
thank you**

```
           Public Function Tampil_Stock(ByVal limit_kar As String) As List(Of Class_stock)
    Dim tmpBaca As New List(Of Class_stock)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dreader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim sql As String
    Try
        sql = "SELECT NoReg,status,status_kartu FROM tb_stock WHERE status= '0' and status_kartu= '0' ORDER BY NoReg ASC limit ?fn"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, myconnection.open)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?fn", MySqlDbType.String, 10)).Value = limit_kar
        dreader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dreader.Read
            Dim objTemp As New Class_stock
            objTemp.NoReg_ = dreader.Item("NoReg")
            'objTemp.NoPin_ = dreader.Item("NoPin")
            objTemp.status_ = dreader.Item("status")
            objTemp.status_kartu_ = dreader.Item("status_kartu")
            tmpBaca.Add(objTemp)
        End While

    Catch sqlex As MySqlException
        Throw New Exception(sqlex.Message.ToString())
    End Try
    myconnection.close()
    Return tmpBaca
    'dreader.Close()
End Function
```

Insert data in listview

```
       Sub Loadlist (Optional ByVal criteria As Integer = 0)
     Dim objList As List (Of Class_stock)
     As String Dim nourut
     objList = stock.Tampil_Stock (criteria)
     nourut = 1
     Me.ListView1.Items.Clear ()
     For i As Integer = 0 To objList.Count - 1
         nourut = ListView1.Items.Count + 1
         Me.ListView1.Items.Add (nourut)
         Me.ListView1.Items (i). SubItems.Add (objList.Item (i). NoReg_)
     Next

 end Sub
```

Comment: Could you paste the error log, please

Comment: what is your database engine?

Comment: codemunkee already improved the writing of code, but why data can not be displayed in a listview? these data in our tables

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`limit_kar` should be an `integer`, you used `string`. Also changed the parameter to `integer` instead of `string`.

```
Public Function Tampil_Stock(ByVal limit_kar As Integer) As List(Of Class_stock)
    Dim tmpBaca As New List(Of Class_stock)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dreader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim sql As String
    Try
        sql = "SELECT NoReg,status,status_kartu FROM tb_stock WHERE status= '0' and status_kartu= '0' ORDER BY NoReg ASC limit ?fn"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, myconnection.open)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?fn", MySqlDbType.Int)).Value = limit_kar
        dreader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dreader.Read
            Dim objTemp As New Class_stock
            objTemp.NoReg_ = dreader.Item("NoReg")
            'objTemp.NoPin_ = dreader.Item("NoPin")
            objTemp.status_ = dreader.Item("status")
            objTemp.status_kartu_ = dreader.Item("status_kartu")
            tmpBaca.Add(objTemp)
        End While

    Catch sqlex As MySqlException
        Throw New Exception(sqlex.Message.ToString())
    End Try
    myconnection.close()
    Return tmpBaca
    'dreader.Close()
End Function
```

Comment: i'm using mysql server

Comment: help me, because I was just learning vb.net with class, how to correct writing, so that it can run sql syntaxt as expected.

Comment: I've tried, you gave error code is gone, but there are no data that appears in the list view. I attach the following listviewnya

Comment: error if ?fn changes (@fn) ..**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@fn' at line 1**

Comment: I'm not really sure why you marked my answer as "accepted" when it's actually not :D.. sorry for the late reply, but is your problem now solved?